# C++ VS2013 strange error C2247?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I faced up a very strange error that I don't understand (using Visual Studio 2013). With the following example:

```
class a {
public:
    a() = default;
};

class b : private a {
public:
    b() = default;
};

class c : public b {
public:
    c() = default;
    a var;    // ERROR C2247
};
```

I got following error:

```
error C2247: 'a' not accessible because 'b' uses 'private' to inherit from 'a'
```

The only way to get it compiled is to change the declaration of 'var' as following:

```
::a var;
```

I'm just curious to understand why do the compiler misinterpret the first declaration of 'var' ? what can it imagine ?

Comment: This is a duplicate.  I am just trying to find it.

Comment: `a` is injected. This is WAI.

Comment: @NathanOliver Oh I think I've seen it? Was it a recent thing about injected name or something?

Comment: @Borgleader Yes.  I just can't find it.  I forgot to favorite it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634637/private-inheritance-name-lookup-error this?

Comment: @Borgleader Thanks for finding that

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15342410/passing-a-pointer-of-inaccessible-private-base-type-to-the-derived-class-method

Comment: Thank you very much for the links and your help. It's obvious now :-)